# ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i am trying to run an ionic application on an android device through this command

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

i am getting this error :

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 11.0.11
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

i already have Android-sdk installed and as environment path :

```
cat: /home/yassine/Android/Sdk: Is a directory
```

and JDK 8 installed :

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
```

i am using ubuntu

Comment: can you guys help please

Comment: I don't know anythink about ionic but please try again (by `env` command) are you really have all needed environment variables for this guide https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android#configuring-command-line-tools ?  2) I know then android studio since v4.2.0 uses java v11 to build android app(https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) but gradle by default uses version defined in system  and need additional argument to override it (-Dorg.gradle.java.home) .